# How to update React context within a test?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, react-testing-library, react-context

I have a List component that renders the data from my context. I would like to assert that the values are displaying correctly, then **update the data inside the context and then assert again that the new updated values are displayed correctly**. How can I achieve this?

Things to note:

- **The second test case in List.test.js is where I need help**
- In that test case I realise that updating `theList` wouldn't work, but it helps illustrate what I want
- I've simplified my code for the purpose of this question. I realise in this example the test is not necessary
- App.js uses the AppContextProvider, but the List.test.js uses a mocked version so I can control what data is inside the context
- I am aware of the [setContext function available in Enzyme](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/setContext.html), but we are updating to React 18 soon and there is no adapter for Enzyme. Additionally, setContext requires the root component that is being rendered to accept the context. Since the real version of the code I'm working on has an apollo client provider at the root level this doesn't work.

**App.js**

```
import './App.css';
import { List } from './List'
import { useAppContext } from './useAppContext';
import { AppContextProvider } from './AppContextProvider';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
        <AppContextProvider>
            <List useAppContext={useAppContext}></List>
        </AppContextProvider>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**List.js**

```
export const List = ({useAppContext}) => {
    const appContext = useAppContext();
    const row = (item, index) => <div data-testid={'element-' + index} key={index}>{item}</div>
    return (
        <div>
            {appContext.list.map(row)}
        </div>
    );
}
```

**List.test.js**

```
import { getByTestId, render } from '@testing-library/react';
import { List } from './List';
import { useAppContext } from './useAppContext';
import { AppContext } from './AppContext';

describe('List', () => {

    // This works
    it('renders list', () => {
        const expected = 'A';
        let theList = ['A'];

        const {container} = render(
            <AppContext.Provider value={{ list: theList }}>
                <List useAppContext={useAppContext}></List>
            </AppContext.Provider>
        );

        const actual = getByTestId(container, 'element-0').textContent;
        expect(actual).toEqual(expected);
    })

    // This doesn't work, how can I achieve something similar?
    // The output of this test case is
    // Expected: "B"
    // Recieved: "A"
    it('updates list when context changes', () => {
        const expected = 'A';
        let theList = ['A'];

        const {container} = render(
            <AppContext.Provider value={{ list: theList }}>
                <List useAppContext={useAppContext}></List>
            </AppContext.Provider>
        );

        const actual = getByTestId(container, 'element-0').textContent;
        expect(actual).toEqual(expected);

        const expectedAfterUpdate = 'B';
        theList = ['B']; // My attempt at 'updating the context' mid test

        const actualAfterUpdate = getByTestId(container, 'element-0').textContent;
        expect(actualAfterUpdate).toEqual(expectedAfterUpdate);
    })
})
```

**AppContext.js**

```
import { createContext } from 'react';

export const AppContext = createContext({});
```

**useAppContext.js**

```
import { useContext } from 'react';
import { AppContext } from './AppContext';

export const useAppContext = () => useContext(AppContext);
```

**AppContextProvider.js**

```
import { AppContext } from './AppContext';

export const AppContextProvider = ({children}) => {
    const defaultList = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
    return (
        <AppContext.Provider value={{list: defaultList}}>
            {children}
        </AppContext.Provider>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution I could find was to update `theList` and then rerender the component in the test. This is the same pattern you would use to update the props of a component during a test.

I'll only list out the second test case from List.test.js since the rest of the code remains unchanged.

**List.test.js** - Second test case

```
it('updates list when context changes', () => {
    const expected = 'A';
    // set the initial value the context will use
    let theList = ['A'];

    // pull out the rerender function from the render function call
    const {container, rerender} = render(
        <AppContext.Provider value={{ list: theList }}>
            <List useAppContext={useAppContext}></List>
        </AppContext.Provider>
    );

    const actual = getByTestId(container, 'element-0').textContent;
    expect(actual).toEqual(expected);

    const expectedAfterUpdate = 'B';
    // update the value the context uses
    theList = ['B'];
    // trigger the rerender with our updated context values
    rerender(<AppContext.Provider value={{ list: theList }}>
        <List useAppContext={useAppContext}></List>
    </AppContext.Provider>)

    const actualAfterUpdate = getByTestId(container, 'element-0').textContent;
    expect(actualAfterUpdate).toEqual(expectedAfterUpdate);
})
```